# Вывод всех выделенных request событий в строку

Tags: php, form, request

Есть такой код:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <p>html<input type="checkbox" name="lg" value="1"></p>
    <p>css<input type="checkbox" name="lg" value="2"></p>
    <p>php<input type="checkbox" name="lg" value="3"></p>
    <p>javascript<input type="checkbox" name="lg" value="4"></p>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    $str = 'Вы знаете: ';
    if(isset($_REQUEST['lg']) and $_REQUEST['lg'] == 1)
    {
        $str .= 'html.';
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['lg']) and $_REQUEST['lg'] == 2)
    {
        $str .= 'css.';
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['lg']) and $_REQUEST['lg'] == 3)
    {
        $str .= 'php.';
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['lg']) and $_REQUEST['lg'] == 4)
    {
        $str .= 'javascript.';
    }
    echo $str;
?>
```

Проблема в том, что если пользователь отметит несколько чекбоксов, то выведится только один из выделенных. А надо чтобы все, возле которых галочку поставит.

Что нужно дописать в код, чтобы это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По мотивам предыдущего ответа, плюс оптимизация:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
  <p>html<input type="checkbox" name="lg[]" value="html"></p>
  <p>css<input type="checkbox" name="lg[]" value="css"></p>
  <p>php<input type="checkbox" name="lg[]" value="php"></p>
  <p>javascript<input type="checkbox" name="lg[]" value="javascript"></p>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$lg = is_array($_REQUEST['lg']) ? $_REQUEST['lg'] : array();
echo 'Вы знаете: ' . join('.', $lg);
?>
```

Comment: ошибку join выдаёт. Можете выложить мой код, только переделанный правильно, а то либо я не так меняю, либо что-то не совсем то(

Comment: Чуток подправил.

Comment: Главное чтобы вы принцип поняли, а не чтобы за вас всё написали, не так ли?

Comment: Спасибо, Yuri. Отлично - коротко и почти понятно!) Конечно я хочу понять принцип работы и у меня вопросик. Прокомментируйте пожалуйста это выражение $lg = is_array($_REQUEST['lg']) ? $_REQUEST['lg'] : array();

Comment: Как я понимаю - это выражение говорит, что если запрошен элемент массива, то вывести его, а если нет, то array();  А почему Вы решили array(); - этого пока не мойму

Comment: В случае, если ни один чекбокс не отмечен, $_REQUEST['lg'] будет null. В этом случае join выдаст ошибку. Поэтому мы проверяем что получили массив, в противном случае вставляем пустой массив.

Comment: Потому что функция join требует массив в качестве второго аргумента.

Comment: т.е. есть у нас условие гласит - если мы имеем массив lg(отмечаем с него элементы) , то взять с него эти элемент(ы), если нет, то вернуть пустой массив array();

Comment: правильно же я понял?

Comment: Да, всё именно так. В переменную $lg запишется либо массив значений отмеченных чекбоксов, либо пустой массив. В последнем случае join даст пустую строку.

Comment: ок! спасибо Вам за терпение и большую помощь !

Answer (score 2):

Нужно у инпутов изменить name на `name="lg[]"`, тогда в `$_REQUEST['lg']` будет массив выбранных значений

**UPD** Обновил ваш код, но вам осталось подумать над оптимизацией решения и рефакторингом

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <p>html<input type="checkbox" name="lg[]" value="1"></p>
    <p>css<input type="checkbox" name="lg[]" value="2"></p>
    <p>php<input type="checkbox" name="lg[]" value="3"></p>
    <p>javascript<input type="checkbox" name="lg[]" value="4"></p>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    $str = 'Вы знаете: ';

    if(isset($_REQUEST['lg'])) {
        if(in_array(1, $_REQUEST['lg']))
        {
            $str .= 'html.';
        }

        if(in_array(2, $_REQUEST['lg']))
        {
            $str .= 'css.';
        }

        if(in_array(3, $_REQUEST['lg']))
        {
            $str .= 'php.';
        }

        if(in_array(4, $_REQUEST['lg']))
        {
            $str .= 'javascript.';
        }
    }

    echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: я заменил lg на lg[] в форме и вообще ни один выделенный чекбокс не выводится. Потом в реквестах заменил тоже lg на lg[] и ничего.

Comment: Теперь проверять нужно как массив `in_array (1, $_REQUEST['lg'], true)` а не как строку

Comment: И так `$_REQUEST['lg[]']` писать не нужно, только так `$_REQUEST['lg']`

Comment: Эх, насколько понял, настолько и пытался заменить это в коде, то что Вы написали, но у меня не срабатывает скрипт((

Comment: поменял name="lg[]" и in_array (1, $_REQUEST['lg'], true) == 1 не срабатывает

Comment: Можете скопировать мой код, только переделанный правильно, а то либо я не так меняю, либо что-то не совсем то(

Comment: Обновил ответ, пробуйте

Comment: не работает + куча ошибок.

Comment: Поправил, пробуйте

Comment: да, сейчас ок, спасибо!!